# Compiling and getting an 'undeclared' message in return

Tags: c++, floating-point

This is the coding I have so far. I'm working with an online complier, and not my normal one, so I'm having trouble finding the problem spot. The goal is to input Fahrenheit and output Centigrade.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()

{
    int fahr=0, cent=0, count=0;

    while(fahr!=-99999)
    {
        count++;
        cin>>fahr>>endl;
        cout<<"Input temperature, in Farhenheit, to be converted to Centigrade" <<endl;


        cent=(5./9.)*(fahr-32)(float);

        cout<<"The input Farhenheit value "<<fahr<<" corresponds to the Centigrade value of "<<cent<<endl;
    }
return 0;
  }
```

UPDATE:

Okay, so this is the corrected code. I caught some of the corrections before I read the comments, and (because I didn't mention it before) I'm a complete beginner. This is all strange territory for me, so I appreciate all feedback. If something I'm doing doesn't make sense, feel free to point it out and/or make suggestions.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()

{
    int fahr=0, cent=0, count=0;

    while(fahr!=-99999)
    {
        count++;
        cin>>fahr;
        cout<<"Input temperature, in Farhenheit, to be converted to Centigrade"<<endl;


            cent=(float)(5./9.)*(fahr-32);

        cout<< "The input Farhenheit value " <<fahr<< " corresponds to the Centigrade value of " <<cent<< endl;
    }
return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Please post the full error, the compiler may simply be complaining that the count value is written to but never read.

Comment: You're casting the result value for `cent` to a `float` when `cent` is type `int`. I'm not sure if it does an implicit cast, but either way that's probably a bad idea.

Comment: Your updated code isn't correct at all. If you want `cent` to be a `float`, then declare it as a `float` and not an `int`. You can't just stick a `(float)` in front of it when assigning it a value to turn it into a `float`. Perhaps you wanted to do something like this: http://ideone.com/nprW9

Comment: Please don't update your code in situ.  Add an update to your post.  This allows other people to see the original message and correlate answers to it.

Comment: Gregor Brandt - The site directed me to the 'edit' below the post to update post. You recommend another method?

Comment: @zeheroe: What you did is fine, although most people put updates underneath the original question.

Comment: @zeheroe:  Ben is correct, most people put the update below the original question so that the original remains intact. I think it just keeps the answers relevant

Answer (score 0):

(float) at the end of the line that starts with "cent" is not syntactic.

Removing it is good, as Is using floats instead of ints throughout in this program.

Answer (score 0):

This line looks like it may be wrong:

```
cent=(5./9.)*(fahr-32)(float);
```

The usual syntax for floating is the form:

```
float sngValue = (float) intValue; // casts an integer to a float
float sngValue = (float) dblValue; // casts a double to a float
```

Why must `fahr` and `cent` be typed `int`? If they must be, then, use:

```
cent = (fahr - 32) * 5 / 9;
```

The formula keeps each intermediate result as an integer and we make divide the last step to reduce round off as much as possible. Otherwise, if fahr and `cent` are typed as `float` you can be a bit more flexible:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int count = 0;
    float fahr = 0.0f, cent = 0.0f;
    while (fahr != -99999.0f)
    {
        count++;
        cin >> fahr >> endl;
        cout<<"Input temperature, in Farhenheit, to be converted to Centigrade" <<endl;
        cent = (5.0f / 9.0f) * (fahr - 32.0f); // no need for casting, everything's in float
        cout << "The input Farhenheit value " << fahr << " corresponds to the Centigrade value of " << cent << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You had a `(float)` keyword at the end of that expression which is not correct usage for casting.

Comment: I also have to code for an average between an input Fahr. and Cent. value.

Answer (score 0):

Your first error has to do with adding `>> endl` after `cin >> fahr`:

```
error: no match for ‘operator>>’ in ‘std::cin.std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>> [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]((* & fahr)) >> std::endl’
```

Remove that and simply have `cin >> fahr;` to read an `int` from `stdin`. You use `std::endl` to add a new-line and flush an output stream (`ostream`) like `cout`, not an input stream such as `cin`.

There's also an error at the line:

```
cent=(5./9.)*(fahr-32)(float);
```

If you want to cast the result of `(5./9.)*(fahr-32)` to a `float` then you would have the cast `(float)` at the beginning.

However, since `cent` is of type `int`, it's even more pointless to do that. Perhaps you wanted to cast `(fahr-32)` to a `float`, either way the cast goes at the front.

**EDIT:** Your updated code has a new error. If you want `cent` to be a `float` then declare it as such: http://ideone.com/nprW9

Comment: I also have to code for an average between an input Fahr. and Cent. value. And AusCBloke, I made that correction. (I've been at this for too long haha /facepalm. Brain is melting.) In looking at this, how would I exclude the sentinel (my -99999) in the calculation?

Comment: @zeheroe: Have the check before the calculation.